# What is the meaning of call: foo(function(params){...});

Tags: javascript, function, call

I am aware of functions being declared and immediately called, like so

```
(function(arg) {...}(value))();
```

but what does this mean:

```
functionName(function(params){...});
```

It is in the (first non code line of the) demo/demo.js file of the [Ace editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) and it is the worst javascript code I have yet encountered. I want to know if it is really poorly written or if I am too novice to decipher it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case,

```
outerFunc(function(params) { ... })
```

contains the definition of their module in an anonymous function, which `outerFunc` uses to control how it's defined. In [the code you're referring to](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/demo.js) they use the  `define` function from [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to do several things, including specifying dependencies and executing context.

`define()` is part of the CommonJS modules specification, and needs to be implemented differently on different JavaScript platforms you're using. This code design is more than reasonable; it's following the proposed specifications that may be a core part of the language in the future.

Comment: `define` is part of commonJS AMD

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous function is passed to the function `functionName()`.

If it's poorly written, or you are too novice, that depends, because it might be just a legit well usage of this style.

Comment: That code is fairly well written, and it was pretty obvious that an anonymous function was being passed to another function. No offense at all intended, but if you didn't pick that up, you're a novice, puk. Passing anonymous functions is pretty much bread and butter Javascript.

Comment: My problem was that I could not find where the functionName function (`define`) was. I prefer there to be a great deal of commenting in my code as in [this](http://easeljs.com/docs/DisplayObject.js.html) piece of code. Now I don't like arrogantly defending my position, but I feel like I am in the right when I claim that this file is overly convoluted. For example, the callbacks are not specified in the index.html file where the elements are created, but in a completely different file. What is the reason for this? It is very difficult to trace.

Answer (score 0):

It is not poorly coded. That is an anonymous function being passed to the function `functionName`. That function will have a name local to functionName and can be called inside it. This can be extremely useful in a lot of cases.

```
sort(my_arr, function(obj1, obj2){ 
        return obj1.age*obj1.color - obj2.age*obj2.color; 
    }
);

function sort(arr, compare){
     // Sorts arr of objects using compare(arr[i], arr[j]);
}
```

This would allow you to implement a single sort function `sort` which works for all possible objects as long as the caller provides a compare function for that type of object.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> (function(arg) {...}(value));
> ```

This is not a function call. You probably meant `(function(params) {...}(value))(someArgs);`.

> ```
> functionName(function(params){...});
> ```

This is a call to function `functionName`, passing that anonymous function in as a parameter.

This is (essentially) the same as:

```
var f = function(params) { ... };
functionName(f);
```

or:

```
function f(params) { ... };
functionName(f);
```

Consider:

```
function functionName(f) {
   f();
}
```

That `...` now gets invoked.

Comment: I think he actually meant `(function(arg) {...})(value);`